# Limit of beta-binomial distribution is binomial

Tags: distributions, beta-distribution, beta-binomial-distribution

I am trying to understand the relationship between the beta-binomial and the binomial distribution. 
More specifically, I am trying to show that the limit of the beta-binomial distribution, with $p=a/(a+b)$  is binomial as $a+b$ goes to infinity. I am having trouble showing it. Any useful hints would be very helpful.

For this, I believe I should take the limit of the $\text{beta}(a,b)$ function as $a+b$ go to infinity. Does this exist? According to an answer below this does not exist. I am also hesitant to use the MGF as it seems nasty.

Comment: The MGF (or better, the CF) is not as nasty as it might seem: it's a hypergeometric function, which means its power series has a nice form.  However, you could just apply Stirling's approximation to the Gamma function to show directly that the probability mass function converges to the Binomial distribution.

Comment: I am trying through sterling's formula. For B(a,b) I seem to get something sensible. However for B(k+a,n-k+b) I don't see how this helps.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are at least two ways of seeing this.

---

The [urn interpretation of the distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta-binomial_distribution#Beta-binomial_as_an_urn_model) can be shown to be

> The beta-binomial distribution can also be motivated via an urn model for positive integer values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$, known as the Polya urn model. Specifically, imagine an urn containing $\alpha$ red balls and $\beta$ black balls, where random draws are made. If a red ball is observed, then two red balls are returned to the urn. Likewise, if a black ball is drawn, then two black balls are returned to the urn. If this is repeated $n$ times, then the probability of observing k red balls follows a beta-binomial distribution with parameters $n$,$\alpha$ and $\beta$.

However if $n$ is negligible compared to the number of balls in the urn, adding a few balls back to the urns makes negligible difference for the next draw. It follows that the distribution is simply that of drawing with replacement, which is binomial.

---

From an algebraic viewpoint, the [distribution is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta-binomial_distribution#As_a_compound_distribution)
$$
{n \choose k}  \frac{B(k + \alpha, n - k + \beta)}{B(\alpha, \beta)}
.
$$

By the [properties of the Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function)

$$
B(x + 1, y) = B(x, y) \frac{x}{x + y},
\\
B(x, y + 1) = B(x, y) \frac{y}{x + y}
$$

Specifically,

$$
B(i + \alpha, n - k + \beta) = B(i - 1 + \alpha, n - k + \beta) \frac{i - 1 + \alpha}{i - 1 + n - k + \alpha + \beta},
$$

and for large $\alpha, \beta$, taking into account the [Taylor series of $\frac{1}{1 + x}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series):

$$
\frac{i - 1 + \alpha}{i - 1 + n - k + \alpha + \beta} = 
\frac{i - 1 + \alpha}{\alpha} \frac{\alpha}{(\alpha + \beta) \left(1 + \frac{i - 1 + n - k}{\alpha + \beta}\right)}
\sim
\frac{i - 1 + \alpha}{\alpha} \frac{\alpha}{(\alpha + \beta)} \left(1 - \frac{i - 1 + n - k}{\alpha + \beta}\right) \sim \frac{\alpha}{(\alpha + \beta)}
.
$$

Continuing this,

$$
\frac{B(k + \alpha, n - k + \beta)}{B(\alpha, \beta)}
\sim
\frac{B(\alpha, \beta)}{B(\alpha, \beta)} \left( \frac{\alpha}{\alpha + \beta}\right)^k \left( \frac{\beta}{\alpha + \beta} \right)^{n - k}
,
$$
and the distribution is approximately binomial.

Comment: I guess I am having one issue with this. Although for large he large $\alpha$ $\beta$ the approximation above makes intuitive sense, really for the limit to converge we should have the condition that $p=\alpha/(\alpha+\beta)$. With this in mind  I am having trouble formally justifying the last approximation. For example, how can I show that $(\alpha+k)/(\alpha+k+\beta)$ tends to p.

Comment: @DanRoDuq I expanded this a bit in the answer.